# What is "@" in ES7 Syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-2016

I was [reading up on `react-dnd`](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/) and it offers code examples in `es5`, `es6` and `es7`. Under the `es7` example, it give the following code:

```
@DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
```

What is this `@` about? Never seen it and can't find it under googling any sort of `es7` references.

Comment: for what it's worth, I found the duplicate by googling [at symbol es7](https://www.google.ca/search?q=at+symbol+es7)

Comment: To be clear, this is not part of ES7, it's a proposal.